# How to interpret this output generated by make command?

Tags: c, bash, makefile, ubuntu-12.04

On running make command, I get the following output,

```
g++ -DUNIX -Wall -g -I../include -I. main.o hfpage.o hfp_driver.o                      test_driver.o db.o new_error.o page.o system_defs.o buf.o -o hfpage 

/usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `error_string_table::error_string_table(Status, char const**)' changed   from 18 in db.o to 34 in buf.o
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `buf.o' is  incompatible with i386 output
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hfpage] Error 1
```

This file generates hfpage.o which when I try to run using `./hfpage.o` I get and error message `bash: ./hfpage.o: cannot execute binary file`.

Is there something wrong with my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first, the error messages says `buf.o` was compiled for another architecture, probably 32 bit on a 64 bit machine.

The reason you can't run `./hprof.o` is that `hprof.o` is a binary object, not an executable.  If this compile had completed, since you have no `-o` flag, the executable would be named `a.out` which for historical reasons is the default name of a UNIX executable.

Your problem probably comes in an earlier step in the make file.  Basically, you should have several lines like

```
main.o: 
   g++ -DUNIX -Wall -g -I../include -I. -c main.C
```

and then a final line like

```
main:
   g++ -DUNIX -Wall -g -o main main.o hfpage.o hfp_driver.o
```

The architecture message suggests you compiled `buf.o` with a different compiler or compiler flags.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to build your app for i386 architecture using x86-64 version of libraries. Most likely you mistakenly installed x86-64 libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like one of the files being linked in is of different binary output than the rest. Make sure that when compiling you are not setting the `-m32 or -m64` flag for `g++` and if you are that it is consistent. Once you do this run a `make clean` and `make` again to make sure that it rebuilds all your binaries in the correct output type.

Also you shouldn't execute `.o` files as they are usually binary objects and not an executable. Check the target in the Makefile to find out what the executable should be.